# React-Native-Material-Dropdown not showing data on Front-end

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have used react-native material dropdown to fetch data from my API as follows:

```
 <Dropdown
        label='colors'
        data={this.state.data.colors}
        containerStyle={{width: 50}}
      />
      {console.log("sbHASB",this.state.data.colors)}
```

However when I implement thi, I do get the colors on my log but they do not seem to appear on the list, it seems to be blank, can anyone please tell me why is ot so?
Any help would be great, thank you.

my logs after implementing are as follows:

```
 sbHASB ["Blue", "White", "Blue", "White", "Blue", "White", "Blue", "White"]
```

Do tell me if you require anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [react-native-material-dropdown](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown), the documentation on their github suggests that the data prop should be a list of objects with a value key. See here the example given.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    let data = [{
      value: 'Banana',
    }, {
      value: 'Mango',
    }, {
      value: 'Pear',
    }];

    return (
      <Dropdown
        label='Favorite Fruit'
        data={data}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

For your list to work you should transform it to match this format, for example

```
const data = this.state.data.colors.map((color) => ({value: color}))
```

Given your example above that could look like

```
<Dropdown
   label='colors'
   data={this.state.data.colors.map((color) => ({value: color}))}
   containerStyle={{width: 50}}
/>
```

However I would advise transforming the data before this step, for example when you receive the response from the api.

see this example on snack.io, the dropdown will work best if you preview it on a device since the animation doesn't display properly on the web preview.

https://snack.expo.io/@dannyhw/dropdown

UPDATE:
Here is the updated example that includes an example of how it can be used dynamically

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: {colors: []}
  }

  getSomeData() {
    // imagine this is your api call here and it returns a promise that resolves to be a list of colours
    return Promise.resolve(["green", "White", "Blue", "White", "Blue", "White", "Blue", "White"])
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getSomeData().then((result)=> {
      this.setState(state => state.data.colors = result) 
    })
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Dropdown
          label='colors'
          data={this.state.data.colors.map((color) => ({value: color}))}
          containerStyle={{width: 150}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is throwing me an error: undefined is not an object(evaluation 'this.state.data.colors.map')

Comment: Can show more of the code so I can understand why you're getting this error?

Comment: I added an example of it working on snack.io to the answer, perhaps that will help.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have to collect the data dynamically from the api itself

Comment: I updated the example on snack to show how you can still do that.

Comment: Hi, am getting an error as undefined is not an object evaluating: this.state.data.map can you help please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207832/discussion-between-danny-and-trina-chaudhuri).